# Return only value that exists in array php

Tags: php, arrays

I have this

```
$array1 = ['apple'];

$array2 = ['apple', 'orange'];
```

I want to check if there is any value from array2 in array1 and return that value. I tried `in_array($array1, $array2);` it returns only true or false.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are looking for [`array_intersect()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php)

```
$array1 = ['apple'];;
$array2 = ['apple', 'orange'];
$result = array_intersect($array1, $array2);
print_r($result);
```

Comment: see I thought this was a crappy question, and then learned something I didn't know!

Answer (score 1):

There is a function `array_intersect()` use that

```
$array1 = ['apple'];
$array2 = ['apple', 'orange'];
//get the same value
$result = array_intersect($array1, $array2);
```

> **array_intersect()** Compare the values of two arrays, and return the matches

Answer (score 0):

[in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) returns `true` or `false`, so when it is true you could add it to an array:

```
$array1 = ['apple'];
$array2 = ['apple', 'orange', 'apple'];
$result = [];
foreach ($array2 as $a2) {
    if (in_array($a2, $array1)) {
        $result[] = $a2;
    }
}
print_r(array_unique($result));
```